# Perl regular expression \U

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am trying to convert some perl code to python. I came across this line

```
if($Var=~ /^\U/)
{ dosomething(); }
```

I have looked over the web for expression, but i am not able to comprehend its meaning.

\U        uppercase till \E

\E        end case modification

Please give an example of the correct usage if possible and how to approach for a python equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the meaning of Perl's `\U` escape. It does not match _anything_ by itself, it just modifies the subsequent pattern to match only uppercase letters. `/^\U/` will match _every_ input.

Comment: Can you give me example usage of \U ?

Comment: @pikapika, `print "\Ufoo\Ebar";`

Comment: `\U` does exactly what the function `uc` does -- turns letters to uppercase.

Comment: Ah ! I get it now. The person who wrote the code wanted to check if the string is all in upper case from the start of the string. so the correct code will be  if( $var=~ /[A-Z]/) dosomething() right ?

Comment: @pikapika No, `/^[A-Z]/`. Assuming that is what is meant. You would have to check the context and see if it makes sense.

Comment: No, that would match any string with at least one capital letter. `/^[A-Z]*$/` would be one way to make sure the string only contains capitals. Or ``/^[A-Z]+$/` if you do not want to match the empty string. edit: My no was at pikapika

Comment: `/^\p{Lu}*\z/` would check that, or `/^[A-Z]*\z/` if you have a very limited definition of letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex engine knows nothing of `\U`. It's processed by the Perl parser in double quoted and regex literals.

```
"\Uabcdef"       is the same as     uc("abcdef")
"\Uabc\Edef"     is the same as     uc("abc")."def"
```

That means that

```
/^\Uabc/         is the same as     /^ABC/
/^\U/            is the same as     /^/
```

---

`/^/` (and thus `/^\U/`) is rather pointless, as it will always match.

If you wanted to make sure a string consists entirely of upper case letters, you'd use `/^\p{Lu}*\z/`, or `/^[A-Z]*\z/` if you have a very limited definition of letter.

---

Perl's

```
$var =~ /\Uabc\Edef/
```

would be written as follows in Python:

```
re.search("abc".upper() + "def", var)
```